# Sqoop Export Error: Mixed update/insert is not supported against the target database yet

Tags: hive, sqoop

I am trying to export my data from Hive table to RDMBS (Microsoft SQL Server 2016 ) using this command:

```sh
sqoop export \
  --connect connectionStirng \
  --username name \
  --password password \
  --table Lab_Orders \
  --update-mode allowinsert \
  --update-key priKey \
  --driver net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver \
  --hcatalog-table lab_orders \
  -m 4
```

I want to do incremental export so I have specified update-mode and update-key. However when I run this command it fails with this error:

```
ERROR tool.ExportTool: Error during export:
Mixed update/insert is not supported against the target database yet
at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.upsertTable(ConnManager.java:684)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:73)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:99)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
```

I went through all possible solutions including removing --driver. if I remove driver it doesn't recognize the RDBMS table. I am using sqoop version 
Sqoop 1.4.6-cdh5.11.1 on cloudera cluster.

Can someone please help with possible solution?

Comment: Can you try removing `--update-mode` flag and see.

Comment: Yes, I tried that but then nothing is inserted in the database.